# How to pass certain values from string to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string something like that:

```
`var string = "This is some the text [and_this] and some more text [and_this2] and also [and_this3]"`
```

What I whish to have an array simple with the brackets value:

```
`{
0: [and_this]
1: [and_this2]
2: [and_this3]
}`
```

So basically I wish to get all the text between the brackets - also the brackets itself - to a new array. Something like "get all the values between the brackets. How could I achieve that? Thanks a lot!

I'm not sure how to start to find all the texts between brackets `forEach(), indexOf()`, any other? And what find push to an array. Any help appreciated.

Comment: RegEx could help you. Are you comfortable with them ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! the linked article helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

No Regex, performance unoptimized straight to the point version, which will also introduce you to the almighty of Js - [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
 var expression= `var string = "This is some the text [and_this] and some more text [and_this2] and also [and_this3]"`;

 var values = expression.split("[").reduce((result, current) => {
        var parts =  current.split("]");
        if (parts.length > 1){
            result.push(parts[0]);
        }
        return result;
    }, []);
```